# Cannot update macOS Mojave 10.14.2 to 10.4.4

Tags: macos, mojave

I have a Mid 2012 MacBook Pro with 512 GB hard drive which dual boots along with macOS Sierra.

I have converted macOS Mojave partition to APFS from Mac OS Extended (Journaled).

When attempting to install macOS Mojave 10.14.4 update, this screen stays for a while and then system restarts to back to macOS Sierra:

[image]

What is going wrong and how do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your 512GB HD is a SSD drive right?
APFS works only on SSD drives. (except for the Fusion drives)

The title of your question says: update macOS Mojave 10.14.2 to 10.4.4 => I think you meant 10.14.4 no?
So, do you really need your system to have that dual boot thingy?
Otherwise, I would recommend you to wipe you hard drive completely and entirely, but you'll loose everything. (that's why you have your backups up to date :-) I hope)
Once your drive is empty, start the installation of macOS Mojave from a USB thumb drive?!

Before doing all that, if your system is still working, first create a Bootable USB thumb drive with the macOS Mojave installation on it.

Don't forget that wiping your hard drive will WIPE all your data!